# radio on a chip

Tags: radio, trf

Can Radios on a Chip be used as RF amplifiers in multi-stage TRF Radios?
MK 484; ZN414;
The idea is to replace tubes with low safe voltage semiconductor modules in retrofitting 1920's TRF Radios as well as building breadboard style STEAMPUNK TRF Radios using Antique/Vintage Components with modern electronics. 
Variometers,Variocouplers Variable Condenser/Coil Assemblies. individual Coils & Variable Condensers

Comment: *The idea is to replace tubes* You should **forget** about doing this, it will not work. (Radio) circuits are not just "a collection of amplifiers" which you can replace with something else. The circuitry needed to make a **tube** work is **entirely different** from what would be needed to make an MK484 or ZN414 work. I give you a 99.99% change of destroying these chips and almost 0 % chance of getting a working radio. What you can do is simply replace **all** electronics with new circuits.

Comment: Find original circuits designed for triodes, and replace them with JFETs like the 2N3819. (Running off 9 or 12V rather than 90V+, of course)

Comment: If you want the 'look' of tubes but not the high voltage just connect up the heaters only (nom. 6V3)  and build the low voltage (modern) radio parts separately, hidden away under the chassis. The 6V3 AC once rectified and smoothed makes a nice DC source for the modern electronics. Passive components such as variable capacitors and inductors etc. can be easily incorporated into the electronics. One advantage of this approach is just about any tube will do.

Answer (score 1):

You mention *multi-stage* TRF radios, like this?:
[image: multi-stage TRF]

This example shows 3-stages amplifier, with four stages of selectivity. The ZN414 has no selectivity of its own: any selective stage must precede the chip. It is not possible to open the chip to drop in the LC resonators **between** amplifier stages.
It may be possible to gang-couple the radio resonators together into one front-end filter, but that's a very difficult re-work.

Comment: Thanks for the response and schematic. My Plans are for individually tuned RF stages ie. Not ganged VariableCondensers.

Comment: The last RF stage will use ZN414 in its normal functions; RF in and Audio Out; driving an LM386 Signal Audio Amplifier; driving a Power PCBoard with Volume Control driving a small Speaker  driving a

Comment: @jjdobrikin OK, could be done. Perhaps you have 4 independent resonators rather than 4 ganged resonators shown above. You'd still want the 3 RF amplifier in-between. Each should be a low-gain stage that has very good output-to-input isolation so that all your resonators "peak" independently. The ZN414 accepts RF at its input, and becomes the "Detector" stage (above).

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, although you'll have the detector included in the RF amplifier. You can keep the vintage tuning circuit and the audio frequency amplifier circuit (connect them with a capacitor).

Comment: hi thanx for the response The plan is for individual Tuned Circuits not ganged The last RF Stage a Radio on a Chip using the Detected output to drive an LM386 Amplifier which drives a power amp PC Board module with Volume Control.

Comment: The plan is for individual Tuned Circuits not ganged The last RF Stage a Radio on Chip using the Detected output to drive an LM386 Amplifier which drives a power PC Board module with Volume Control. The upfront RF Stages to be semiconductor Module or hollow state, 12 volt Space Charge Tubes from yesteryear. What I am trying to do is use the Radio on a Chip output of RF & Audio not shunting the RF to ground.  If you look at an Atwater Kent Model 20 Schematic you will see that it uses 3 separate  A B & C voltages no complex circuitry to derive desired voltages on Plates Grids and Filaments.

Comment: U must use different integrated circuits in this case. The ones you mentioned have audio range output. I would personally use ATR4251, but I don't recommend it. It's obsolete and has a low gain. I would only use it for myself.